# Sitecore SXA override Search Controller

Tags: sxa

I am using Sitecore 9.3 with SXA search components (search box, search results, filters and paging) and needs to extend this to read data from custom API.

What I have thought of is to clone the search results components and update the API calls for search box and filters. But I need to know whether there is any easier way to achieve this like only overriding the search controller?

Comment: What do you mean with "read data from custom api"? What do you have to achieve?

Comment: I need to get data from external source and append it to the search results items list that is returned from sitecore

Comment: Append it as extra results? Or append extra data to the result items?

Comment: this means that i need to override the SXA search controller?

Comment: Not necessarily.. it depends on what you want. That's why I'm asking more information. If you just want to append extra data to the search results that were fetched by the SXA code you can do it without overrides but I'm not yet sure that is what you need.. Is it? Or do you want to extend the search result set itself?

Comment: yes i want to extend the sxa search result itself

Comment: @NAli, does this link help - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/20182/4515?
Basically you need to fetch search results from a custom API correct?